# how to get dynamic table data in html in reponse in JMeter

Tags: html, jmeter

I am using the JMeter3.0. In my project I visited pages where the dynamic table contents are displayed as in the response.

Actually tabular format is showing, but data are not showing, and I would require data to extract values from those.

Can someone help me our here?

Comment: By "dynamic content" you mean that it is generated by JavaScript in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the full response data it may mean that the data is being populated using i.e. [AJAX technology](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) by secondary JavaScript request(s).

As per [JMeter Project](http://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if your table is being populated via AJAX requests you need to simulate these requests somehow and get data from their responses. AJAX requests can be recorded using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), but when it comes to replaying them you need to do it a little bit differently comparing to "normal" sequential HTTP Requests, see [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article to learn how AJAX requests can be handled in JMeter tests.